# How to get the subsite url from an image url in SharePoint Online using JavaScript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, url, display-template

I have a list of urls pointing to images, which are originated in various subsites - sometimes burried in nested folder structures. Now, my question is: Is there any way I can derive the url of the containing subsite from such image url within the code of a display template?

I know it's not possible by pure string operations, since the folder structures have no clear pattern, but I hoped I somehow could get the context of the subsite and work from there. Something like this:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext(imageUrl);
var subsiteUrl = ctx.get_web().get_url();
```

Unfortunately, the context I receive from the imageUrl is invalid.
Any ideas? Thx!

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behavior to receive invalid context from image URL where you should provide absolute **Site URL**.

So You will need to split the URL first to get the Site URL as mentioned at [How to split URL to get URL path in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334400/how-to-split-url-to-get-url-path-in-javascript)

**Alternatively**, Instead of splitting image URL to get site URL you can use `SP.ClientContext.get_current()` as the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadSiteURL, "sp.js"); });
function loadSiteURL() {
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.site = ctx.get_site();
ctx.load(this.site);
this.web = ctx.get_web();
ctx.load(this.web);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));
}

function onSuccess(sender, args) {
   alert(this.site.get_url());
}
funtion onFail(sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response! However, this is actually not what I am lokking for. As I mentioned, the images are stored in folders of different depths like "mysitecollection.com/subsite1/folder1/folder2/imageA.jpg" and "mysitecollection.com/subsite2/subsite2b/folder1/imageB.jpg". So I cannot use string splitting in order to receive the urls "mysitecollection.com/subsite1/" and "mysitecollection.com/subsite2/subsite2b". It's just not a clear pattern to work with.

Comment: and your second suggestions requires that I already know the parent subsite of the images. But that's exactly what I am lokking for. And in the general case it is NOT the one I am currently in

Comment: Bro, why you concentrate on image URL ?! where will you add your code? so SP.ClientContext.get_current will solve your issue I'm confused why you restricted with image URL!

Comment: It does not matter whether the URL refers to an image or any other resource. The problem is, that with SP.ClientContext.get_current(), ctx.get_site() and ctx.get_web() I only get the CURRENT site/page. But I am interested in the site where the image (or other resource) lays in. And the only information I have is the absolute url of this image/resource.